# Get meta tag content by name, beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, metadata

I'm trying to get the meta data from this website(here's the code).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.svpboston.com/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")

title = soup.find("meta", name="description")
image = soup.find("meta", name="og:image")

print(title["content"] if title else "No meta title given")
print(image["content"]if title else "No meta title given")
```

however I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Work/Web Scraping/Selenium/sadsaddas.py", line 9, in <module>
    title = soup.find("meta", name="description")
TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **[`bs4 docs`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#the-keyword-arguments)**:

> You can't use a keyword argument to search
> for HTML’s `name` element, because Beautiful Soup uses the name
> argument to contain the name of the tag itself. Instead, you can give
> a value to ‘name’ in the attrs argument

To grab tag by specific attribute, I recommend you putting it into dictionary and pass that dictionary into `.find()` as the `attrs` argument. But you passed wrong attribute to grab title and image as well. You should be grabbing `meta` tag with `property=<...>` rather than `name=<...>`. Below is the final code to get what you need:

```
import requests
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('https://www.svpboston.com/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")

title = soup.find("meta", attrs={'property': 'og:title'})
image = soup.find("meta", attrs={'property': 'og:image'})

print(title["content"] if title is not None else "No meta title given")
print(image["content"] if title is not None else "No meta title given")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
title = soup.find("meta", attrs={"name":"description"})
image = soup.find("meta", attrs={"name":"og:image"})
print(title)
print(image)
print(title["content"] if title else "No meta title given")
print(image["content"] if image else "No meta for image given")
```

## or

```
title = soup.find("meta", property="og:title")
print(title["content"] if title else "No meta title given")
```

Answer (score -1):

find() only takes one argument. Use this instead:

```
meta = soup.findall("meta")
title = meta.find(name="description")
image = meta.find(name="og:image")
```